# Notification icon?

Tags: android, notifications

I create a notification via the standard code, the example below. Through the standard Image Asset I create an icon, I find it in the code.
When I start the notification, as an icon I see another icon, see the map.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the process of creating an icon:
Create the Notification Icon
Go to File> New> Image Asset.
From the Icon Type dropdown, select Notification Icons.
Click on the icon next to the Clip Art item to select a material icon that you will use as the icon for your notification. In this example, you can use the Android icon.

```
public void onCreateNotif(View view) {
    String chanal_Id = "default_chanal_id";

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, chanal_Id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action1)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Notification text")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

here is the file tree

[image]

here I see this icon in the notification

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project so as to sync your assets

Comment: tried, the problem remained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Solution:** 
when you create Image Asset so It will create 3 Xmls files :

1. Background xml : it only contains on background color and shape
2. Foreground xml : it contains on foreground. only icon without
       background color or shape
3. Integration of background and foreground xmls and it can be found in mipmap folder.

So To use the icon you have made in image asset change this line:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action1);
```

To:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

or To this line if you wanted it rounded:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
```

Comment: Thank you, you are attentive. In the issue of typo. Fcatically, the file in the derv and the file in the code have the same name.

Comment: the problem remains, maybe I'm adding icons with an error?